Scala Akka HTTP problem adding multiple segment variables to API URL Routes
I am building an API to track student data using Scala, Akka HTTP, and Akka Actors.
But the API Routes below are not giving me the desired result.
The routes littlerock/admins and littlerock/schools/1 work as expected, but the rest show the error The requested resource could not be found.
I want the API to look for example like below.
All district admins - GET: http://localhost:8080/littlerock/admins
A school's details - GET: http://localhost:8080/littlerock/schools/{1}
All a school's students - GET: http://localhost:8080/littlerock/schools/{1}/students
A student's details - GET: http://localhost:8080/littlerock/schools/{1}/students/{1}
All the student's classmates - GET: http://localhost:8080/littlerock/schools/{1}/students/{1}/classmates
A student's classmate details - GET: http://localhost:8080/littlerock/schools/{1}/students/{1}/classmates/{1}
Could you help me fix the issue!
Thanks in advance!
The Routes code looks like below:

  val schoolRoutes: Route =
    pathPrefix("littlerock") {
    concat(

    pathPrefix("admins") {
      concat(
        pathEnd {
          concat(
            get {
              complete("District administrators.")
            })
        })
    },

    pathPrefix("schools") {
      concat(
        path(Segment) { name =>
          concat(
            pathEnd {
            get {
              rejectEmptyResponse {
                  complete("A school's details.")
              }
            }
            },
            path("students") {
              concat(
                pathEnd {
                  get {
                    rejectEmptyResponse {
                      complete("All students")
                    }
                  }
                },
                path(Segment) { name =>
                  concat(
                    pathEnd {
                    get {
                      rejectEmptyResponse {
                        complete("A student's details")
                      }
                    }},
                    path("classmates") {
                      concat(
                        pathEnd {
                          get {
                            rejectEmptyResponse {
                              complete("A student's classmates.")
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        path(Segment) { name =>
                          concat(
                            get {
                              rejectEmptyResponse {
                                complete("A classmate's details.")
                              }
                          })
                        }
                      )
                    }
                  )
                }
              )
            }
          )
      })
    }
  )}



Look's good at first. Unless you've got a typo. I'd recommend to minimize the problem: write the minimum code required for littlerock/schools/{1}/students to work for instance and see what it does.

Like @johanandren suggested, I replaced all except the last path with pathPrefix.
And the code now works!
The Routes code now looks like below:

  val schoolRoutes: Route =
    pathPrefix("littlerock") {
    concat(

    pathPrefix("admins") {
      concat(
        pathEnd {
          concat(
            get {
              complete("District administrators.")
            })
        })
    },

    pathPrefix("schools") {
      concat(
        pathPrefix(Segment) { name =>
          concat(
            pathEnd {
            get {
              rejectEmptyResponse {
                  complete("A school's details.")
              }
            }
            },
            pathPrefix("students") {
              concat(
                pathEnd {
                  get {
                    rejectEmptyResponse {
                      complete("All students")
                    }
                  }
                },
                pathPrefix(Segment) { studentName =>
                  concat(
                    pathEnd {
                    get {
                      rejectEmptyResponse {
                        complete("A student's details")
                      }
                    }},
                    pathPrefix("classmates") {
                      concat(
                        pathEnd {
                          get {
                            rejectEmptyResponse {
                              complete("A student's classmates.")
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        path(Segment) { classmateName =>
                          concat(
                            get {
                              rejectEmptyResponse {
                                complete("A classmate's details.")
                              }
                          })
                        }
                      )
                    }
                  )
                }
              )
            }
          )
      })
    }
  )}



The reason is that path(...) matches against the full request path left, but you are using it to try to match prefixes of path, if you use pathPrefix(...) instead in the places where you do not want to match the full path up to the end that should sort it.

Could you kindly edit the code above so I try to implement

Since you have pathEnd in there it should work if you replace all except the last path with pathPrefix

Thanks! Changing path to pathPrefix fixes the issue for most of the Routes.
However, the routes littlerock/schools/{1}/students and littlerock/schools/{1}/students/{1}/classmates still display the error The requested resource could not be found, even after the changes. What did I miss?

Sorry, the issue with the students and classmates URL was caused by an error that had nothing to do with the above URL paths. So your earlier suggestion works correctly for all URLs paths! Thanks!
